# ExtJs CallParent() not working in initComponent When try to call from Ajax.request Success

Tags: extjs

I am try to create async Dynamic grid in extjs.but I am not be able to figure out how to call callParent() after ajax call complete.

I am trying to call callParent() in Ajax.request() but it gives me 
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'superclass' of undefined.

```
    initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    this.loadData(function (fields, columns, data) {

        me.store = {
            fields: fields,
            data: data
        };

        me.columns = columns;
        console.log('inner');
        me.callParent(arguments);
    });
    console.log('outer');
    //this.callParent(arguments); //I have try outside of the ajax request but it will call before ajax request compelte.
}

, loadData: function (parent) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'Url',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' },
        //async: false,
        success: function (response, opts) {
            var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            res = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            ...
            ...
            parent.call(this, fields, columns, data);

        },

        failure: function (response, opts) {

        }

    });
}
```

I need to call async call of ajax in InitComponent.

Comment: This can't work with `callParent`, you can use `reconfigure` instead.

Comment: Thanks its working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't work with `callParent` this way, use [`reconfigure`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) instead:

> Reconfigures the grid or tree with a new store and/or columns. Stores and columns may also be passed as params.